# Safari Web Speech API

Tags: macos, safari, speech-recognition, beta, webspeech-api

I updated Safari to 11 beta on macOS Sierra (v10.12.6) searching for working Web Speech API, as https://developer.apple.com/safari/features/ mentioned the following:
"Web Speech API
Support for the Web Speech API, Safari can convert text to speech and vice versa, allowing developers to create accessible, voice-driven web apps."

But it seems to me in Safari still doesn't have option for speech to text via Web Speech API in HTML. Does Safari really support or will support Web Speech API?